# SVG animations and Android/iOS development

Tags: android, ios, animation, svg, motion

I created some animations for a mobile app, now I need to provide assets for Android and iOS developers.

Usually we use a PNG sequence. But I really want to find a solution to migrate to 'vector' (I mean not raster) elements.

I can deliver very clean and light **SVG** files. Is that something that developers can process and transform in what they need?

*Ps: I cant's export the animations to AfterEffects at the moment, so Lottie is not a solution for now.*

Comment: Can someone explain to me (sincerely) why my question was not interesting for the forum? Seen 21 times, but zero answers and comments. Maybe because too simplistic? Not enough expert in terms of coding? Or maybe it's not about the content, it's about the way I wrote it?